# How to get intellisense for value in readonly string array property inside object without using generics

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'll keep it short and sweet.
Why does this

```js
type ReadonlyStringArray = readonly string[]

type TEnumGeneric<EnumIsh extends ReadonlyStringArray> = {
    type: "enum",
    values: EnumIsh
}

type TEnumImplied = {
    type: "enum",
    values: ReadonlyStringArray
}
type EVal<T extends TEnumImplied> = {
    value: T["values"][number]
}
```

Allow for this

```
const somearr = ["foo", "baz", "bar"] as const
const x: TEnumGeneric<typeof somearr> = {
    type: "enum",
    values: somearr
}
const z: EVal<typeof x> = {
    value: "bar"
}
```

But also allows for this?

```
const y: TEnumImplied = {
    type: "enum",
    values: ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const
} as const
const z: EVal<typeof y> = {
    value: "" //???
}
```

I would assume that it would just allow for one of the values in y.values since values for TEnumImplied is readonly...?

Comment: I don't think the TypeScript compiler knows which values are in TEnumImplied.values, so it instead only allows for values that are the same type as the values in TEnumImplied.values (string type).

Comment: You annotated the type of `y` to be `TEnumImplied`, and `TEnumImplied["values"][number]` is `string`.  If you didn't want that, you shouldn't have annotated `y` that way... this sort of thing is one of the reasons `satisfies` exists, so you can check a value's assignability to a type without widening a variable to that type... see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1ae2w).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz  Thank you so much! It works! You should make this an answer.

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [annotate a variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with a non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type like `TEnumImplied`, then that's all the compiler knows about it.  You can assign a [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) value to it, but that doesn't affect the type of the variable. (Maybe you were expecting some sort of [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments), but that only happens to variables of union types.)

So given

```
const y: TEnumImplied = {
  type: "enum",
  values: ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const
} as const
```

The type of `y` is just `TEnumImplied` and has nothing to do with `"foo"`, `"bar"`, or `"baz"`:

```
y
//^? const y: TEnumImplied
```

And thus `EVal<typeof y>` is just `{ value: string; }`, since `TEnumImplied["values"][number]` is `string`:

```
type E = EVal<typeof y>
//   ^? type E = { value: string; }
```

If you don't like this behavior, you shouldn't annotate `y`'s type.

---

Presumably you just want to *check* that `y`'s type is assignable to `TEnumImplied` without actually *widening* it to that.  That looks like a job for [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  Instead of writing `const vbl: Type = expr;` you can write `const vbl = expr satisifies Type`.  Both versions will give you an error if `expr` is not of type `Type`, but the annotation widens `vbl` to `Type`, while `satisfies` will infer the type of `vbl` to be the type of `expr` (with `Type` as merely a [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) to help with the inference).

So if we change it to:

```
const y = {
  type: "enum",
  values: ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const
} as const satisfies TEnumImplied;
```

Now you'll see the expected type for `y`:

```
y
//^? const y: { 
//     readonly type: "enum"; 
//     readonly values: readonly ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; 
//   }
```

and therefore the expected result for `EVal<typeof y`>:

```
type E = EVal<typeof y>
//   ^? type E =  { value: "foo" | "bar" | "baz"; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.2.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAShCACYD2wGpAysQE4CWwA5gILt2IUkgC8SdjQZMRUDtx4BtALr5CJcsgAqAUWABXMAHEIwCF3gAePYYCSUABZIIAD2KnaUJNTqNmbLl4BIVIAPjE8dSIyCgAuJAAiU0MEgBoopAA3TH1oeJswewd1AF81aM0kXQNCsBgMTghaCIIiCrjE5LA0jOyMXKh4n2l-eSDBYVL1GOQdADVMSy1nNw8vars6hqbw8Va2vtz4rUUEw+gE5UUagCNzVSIy9VBIWARkPmBgemIQd2b9kR4Iw5EhSMcCrYto1mnsMu0IPEkjUem0Djk8khTgAzej0NKJG4gdgEhJErCXJAgLzA4ByDIlKk0kHEDKkDIAeg5AD0APxIWmg8FVSHQpoZGZIHQReaLGb0bFg0KcjltPkaChSlpZDHxOSBHgAbiQZTRguISCw+QWGEs8sVYRa8J1-URiQSSC5vO9DKmz3A0DgiCQLD+nCg2MaXkBApZYKdaIRSK6qMT50GWISuPxqUJxNJ5Mp1NjdNZaMZxfNSCgYYjUZFNSh9RhhrZKvVVeFuAkUj8IhmyZRxskvhkLoG8RHIxEOLxBfzubJIApymNprakul4lltvtSpVav5m4ieHHbqzc6QAB88yTr3mKWvym0q1gAEzWuWaBVKhNp3Xup6HIAISgb6folEAA)